# Facebook Graph API: Retrieving User Friend's Info

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph-api-explorer

given an app using facebook graph API and a logged in user, is it possible to retrieve programmatically likes/movies/music of a friend of the logged in user?

I'm trying to achieve that with the graph explorer but I'm getting empty data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, all friend permissions have been removed. You are only supposed to get data of users who authorized your App.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: you´re welcome :) - please don´t forget to mark my answer as correct, to keep the answer rate on stackoverflow high :)